# Windows Phone Text Cutting

Tags: windows-phone-8, scroll, windows-phone, viewer

I'm developing an app on Windows Phone 8, but when I select data from the Web service, it's cutting.

This is my code:

```
<Grid Background="Aqua">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Background="Yellow" >
        <ItemsControl>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black" x:Name="tbIcerik" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Icerik}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}">


                </TextBlock>

        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>



    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
</Grid>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot you could add? That might help people understand the issue.

Comment: http://imgim.com/96incip253504.png                http://imgim.com/5634inciy3500787.png     this image maybe show you what am i wrong

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding a margin to the Textblock control

Answer (score 1):

Mehmet,

If you are new to the Windows Mobility Designing Please go through this link. Its very simple to understand 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207025%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

After that You can go through Metro Design Guidelines as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The text block has a limitation of how many characters it can print. If the data you are getting is very huge , there are chances that when you scroll down , other parts of data is being truncated ! 
Let me know the response you are getting so that I can assist you further

Answer (score 0):

Add Margin to your TextBlock name tbIcerik i.e Margin="10,0,0,10". This will leave equal space in front and back.